# CoreDNS Not resolving service url outside namespace with K8S / Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I have a local cluster with minikube 1.6.2 running.

All my pods are OK, I checked the logs individually, but I have 2 db, influx and postgres, are not accesible anymore from any url outside namespace.

I logged into both pods, and I can confirm that each db is OK, has data, and I can connect manually with my user / pass.

Let's take the case of influx.

```
kubectl exec -it -n influx blockchain-influxdb-local-fb745b98c-vbghp -- influx -username='myuser' -password="mypass" -database="mydb" -precision=rfc3339 -execute "show measurements"
```

gives me 4 measurements, so no pb.

but when I try to connect influx from the same namespace with his local dns, I get a timeout.

```
➜ ~ kubectl get svc -n influx 
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
blockchain-influxdb-local   ClusterIP   10.96.175.62   <none>        8086/TCP    19m


➜ ~ kubectl get deployments -n influx
NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
blockchain-influxdb-local   1/1     1            1           20m


➜  ~ kubectl get po -n influx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
blockchain-influxdb-local-fb745b98c-vbghp   1/1     Running   0          21m
measures-api-local-8667bb496f-4wp8d         1/1     Running   0          21m
```

Case where it works:

From a pod inside the same namespace:

```
curl --verbose -G 'http://blockchain-influxdb-local:8086/query?db=mydb&pretty=true' --data-urlencode 'u=myuser' --data-urlencode 'p=mypass' --data-urlencode 'precision=rfc3339' --data-urlencode 'q=show measurements'
```

From a pod in another namespace (same namespace), with pod IP

```
curl --verbose -G '172.17.0.5:8086/query?db=mydb&pretty=true' --data-urlencode 'u=myuser' --data-urlencode 'p=mypass' --data-urlencode 'precision=rfc3339' --data-urlencode 'q=show measurements'
```

From a pod in another namespace (same namespace), with service IP

```
curl --verbose -G '10.96.175.62:8086/query?db=mydb&pretty=true' --data-urlencode 'u=myuser' --data-urlencode 'p=mypass' --data-urlencode 'precision=rfc3339' --data-urlencode 'q=show measurements'
```

But when I use local dns from outside namespace, it won't work, I get a timeout from CURL:

```
 curl --verbose -G 'blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local:8086/query?db=mydb&pretty=true' --data-urlencode 'u=myuser' --data-urlencode 'p=mypass' --data-urlencode 'precision=rfc3339' --data-urlencode 'q=show measurements'
```

I followed those debug step to ensure DNS is working, and had no problem, everything works.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

Inside same pod, when I ping this url, I get:

```
root@metadata-api-local-8b4b7846b-zllb8:/go/src/gitlab.com/company/metadata_api# ping blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local

PING nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr (212.95.74.75) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 47ms
```

I don't know why is it making a reference to `nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr`

I also tried to remove local cluster and redeploy it, also tried to update minikube to latest version (1.8.2), nothing worked.

I don't know what else to do...

Has anyone an idea ? I was working well for monthes, don't really know what happened. :(

In response to @Arghya Sadhu, I post the file /etc/resolv.conf from the Influx pod:

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search influx.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local numericable.fr
options ndots:5
```

`kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system`

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-19T10:59:28Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "176"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: 0797c1a9-e9db-4b4c-bc8d-4c7ecca24968
```

EDIT:

```
kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local                                         
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.numericable.fr   canonical name = nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr.
Name:   nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr
Address: 212.95.74.75
```

Comment: Have you checked your DNS apart from these applications? Please, run this `kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml` and post the output for `kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default`. Additionally, post the output for `kubectl exec dnsutils cat /etc/resolv.conf` so we can compare it with your older pods.

Comment: Yes, I have already done those checks as I wrote on my post > https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/ everything seems fine

Comment: Okay, so please post the output for `kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local` as I understood it's resolving the name, right?

Comment: done. gave: server can't find blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN. Please find whole output on the end of the post

Comment: Have you tried removing/creating this service? If not, please run `kubectl get svc blockchain-influxdb-local -n influx -o yaml  --export > blockchain-influxdb-local-svc.yaml; kubectl delete -f blockchain-influxdb-local-svc.yaml; kubectl apply -f blockchain-influxdb-local-svc.yaml`

Comment: to your first question, I was connected to my prod cluster sorry :( So, the result for my loca cluster is:  --> `blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.numericable.fr canonical name = nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr.` it seems not right. I don't know why there is the suffix .numericable.fr at the end. For the info, numericable is my ISP. Check the end of the post for whole output

Comment: If you create a new pod, the same information will be propagated to the new pod?

Comment: How should I check this ? checking /etc/resolv.conf in new pod ?

Comment: Please, ignore my last comment. Let's focus in a different direction. Please, post output for the following 3 commands:

`$ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx`
`$ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local`
`$ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.`

Comment: I put the result in a gist: https://gist.github.com/xoco70/ea6a99ce7acb31cb06c78e7bfffeaf78

Comment: This is happening because your last domain (numericable.fr
o) gives positive answer even if it doesn't have such record. I will write an answer explaining how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into a few possibilities we came across the output for the following commands:

```
$ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx
```

```
$ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local
```

```
$ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.
```

Output for these commands [here](https://gist.github.com/xoco70/ea6a99ce7acb31cb06c78e7bfffeaf78) (adding to the end of this answer for future reference in case of link doesn't work).

Reviewing this output we can see that no matter what `numericable.fr` is always giving positive answer to dns queries.

To avoid this situation you can change ndots entry to 1 or even 0 in your pods.

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search influx.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local numericable.fr
options ndots:0
```

From man pages we have:

> ndots:n
>                 Sets a threshold for the number of dots which must appear
>                 in a name given to res_query(3) (see resolver(3))  before
>                 an  initial absolute query will be made.  The default for
>                 n is 1, meaning that if there are any dots in a name, the
>                 name  will  be tried first as an absolute name before any
>                 search list elements are appended to it.  The  value  for
>                 this option is silently capped to 15.

A more effective and long term solution is to add this entry in the pod/statefulset/deployment manifest as in this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: dns-example
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: nginx
  dnsConfig:
    options:
      - name: ndots
        value: "0"
```

Output from commands referenced for future reference:

```
➜  ~ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx 

Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.default.svc.cluster.local, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  cluster.local
    origin = ns.dns.cluster.local
    mail addr = hostmaster.cluster.local
    serial = 1584628757
    refresh = 7200
    retry = 1800
    expire = 86400
    minimum = 30
    ttl = 10
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.default.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local
    internet address = 10.96.72.6
    ttl = 10
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Name:   blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.72.6

pod "dnsutils" deleted
pod default/dnsutils terminated (Error)
➜  ~ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local 

Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.default.svc.cluster.local, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  cluster.local
    origin = ns.dns.cluster.local
    mail addr = hostmaster.cluster.local
    serial = 1584628757
    refresh = 7200
    retry = 1800
    expire = 86400
    minimum = 30
    ttl = 30
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.default.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.svc.cluster.local, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  cluster.local
    origin = ns.dns.cluster.local
    mail addr = hostmaster.cluster.local
    serial = 1584628757
    refresh = 7200
    retry = 1800
    expire = 86400
    minimum = 30
    ttl = 30
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.cluster.local, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  cluster.local
    origin = ns.dns.cluster.local
    mail addr = hostmaster.cluster.local
    serial = 1584628757
    refresh = 7200
    retry = 1800
    expire = 86400
    minimum = 30
    ttl = 30
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.numericable.fr, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.numericable.fr
    canonical name = nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr.
    ttl = 30
    ->  nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr
    internet address = 212.95.74.75
    ttl = 30
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Non-authoritative answer:
blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.numericable.fr   canonical name = nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr.
Name:   nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr
Address: 212.95.74.75

pod "dnsutils" deleted
pod default/dnsutils terminated (Error)
➜  ~ kubectl run dnsutils -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=tutum/dnsutils -- nslookup -debug blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local.
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local
    internet address = 10.96.72.6
    ttl = 30
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Name:   blockchain-influxdb-local.influx.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.72.6

pod "dnsutils" deleted
```